# How to to pass data from controller to view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I try to pass data from login view to Empinput view. I try to use Http session was not working for data passing.

I got this error:

> "HttpSessionStateBase' does not contain a definition for 'SetString' and no accessible extension method 'SetString' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpSessionStateBase' could be found".

I put code below please tell me how to pass data?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DemoEmployee.Models;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public ActionResult Login(Models.Member model)
{
    var userr = db.User.Where(x => x.UserName == model.UserName && x.Password == model.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            
    name = model.UserName;

    if (userr == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username and password");
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false); 
    }
    else
    {
        // This is not working for passing data to another view
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Username", model.UserName.ToString());
        return RedirectToAction("Empinput", "Empinput");    
    }

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Empinput(Employee model)
{
        Member member = new Member();
        Login sdm = new Login();

        // this is not working for passing data from Login view
        String name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username"); 
}
```

Comment: Try to clean your solution, rebuild it. Or reinstall `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` package.

Comment: Also, try to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` package and rebuild again.

Comment: Avoid Session as much as possible. Instead use ViewBag, hidden input controls, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are different approaches to pass values from a controller to a view.

1. TempData

In your controller function, you may initialize a TempData and then use it in your view. But it will only hold the value in one request.
For eg,
`TempData["UserName"] = model.UserName;`

and then in the view,
You can either store the value to a variable and then display the variable value or display the tempData value directly.
eg,

`var UserName = TempData["UserName"] as string;`

2. ViewData

ViewData also behaves and operates like a TempData

`ViewData["UserName"] = model.UserName;`
and then use it in the view.

3. ViewBag

In controller,

`ViewBag.UserName = model.UserName`

and in View you can use it as

`@ViewBag.UserName`

4. You can use Simple sessions

`Session["UserName"] = model.UserName;`

5. If your Model has more items that you need to be passed to your view, You can also use a view model and then pass the entire model to the view.

I hope this helps you! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy. You can pass your data to view by `ViewBag`.

In your controller:

```
ViewBag.[write a name for View Bag]  = [Your Value]
```

It's like a variable but it's dynamic.

In your for example View:

```
<td>@ViewBag.[Viewbag name]</td>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just call it as a method brother.

[image]

https://github.com/EmpeRoar/StackOverFlowSolutions/blob/main/SO-Solutions/SO.Mvc31/Controllers/EmployeeController.cs

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public EmployeeController()
    {

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult>  Login()
    {
        var emp = new Employee()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Vladimir Bacosa"
        };
        await EmpInput(emp);
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EmpInput(Employee emp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(emp.Name);
        return View();
    }
}
```